# Python for loop executing once for size 2 array

Tags: python, opencv

There seems to be something strange going on in this loop. I tried to debug it, and I have no explanation for what is going on.

This code is from another Stack Overflow post, and I made some edits to it.

```
modelImages = ['/home/lie/Desktop/dylan.jpg','/home/lie/Desktop/melissa.jpg']

for modelImage in modelImages:

    **print modelImage**

    template=cv2.imread(modelImage)
    templateg = cv2.cvtColor(template,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    keys = surf.detect(templateg)

    keys,desc = surfDescriptorExtractor.compute(templateg, keys)

    count = 0



    for h,des in enumerate(desc):

        des = np.array(des,np.float32).reshape((1,64))

        retval, results, neigh_resp, dists = knn.find_nearest(des,1)
        res,dist =  int(results[0][0]),dists[0][0]


        if dist<0.1: # draw matched keypoints in red color
          count=count + 1


    print "space"**
```

The important parts have asterisks. This is a portion of the code that was suppose to identify similarities among images of faces. What the code does is not important. The strange part is that this loop is executing 1 time for an array of size two.

The output is:

```
/home/lie/Desktop/dylan.jpg
/home/lie/Desktop/melissa.jpg
space
```

Notice that both strings in modelImages are printed before space. By the way this is part of a function that is called from a loop. This seems to be more of a python issue than an opencv issue. It almost seems like there is a hidden continue statment

Thanks

Comment: You had a return statement in a previous edit - what happened to that?  There's clearly something else happening outside of the code you provided.  I'd recommend reducing your code to a minimal example that results in the same error.  My bet is you'll find your problem that way.

Comment: I removed the return because I realized I didn't post the whole function, which waant an issue. In addition, I tried doing a smaller version and it printed fine. In addition i tried printing values from the original code and it worked fine to.

Comment: As I see it, the code as is should work as expected.  The issue must reside in a different part of the function.

Comment: Ok, I'll take a further look at it. Thank you. I just wanted to make sure it wasn't some random python issue I was getting. In addition, I don't know if you're familar with opencv and SURF, but I do get a strange error once in a while that randomly goes away: trainData data type =17 is not suported. I don't know if this could play a part.

Comment: The images are being compared to one that is not present in the code snippet I gave you. Strangely, I rewrote the code the exact same way and the problem just went away... however the trainData data type =17 is not supported still comes back every once in a while